# First program ever refactoring

Tags: python, python-3.x

is there anyway to improve? Thank you!

```
def fahren_to_celsius(fahrenheit):
    return round((fahrenheit - 32) / 1.8, 2)
def celsius_to_fahrenheit(celsius):
    return round((celsius * 9/5) + 32)
def celsius_to_kelvin(celsius):
    return round(celsius + 273.15)
def kelvin_to_celsius(kelvin):
    return round(kelvin - 273.15)
def integer_to_absolute(integer):
    return abs(integer)
def print_error_message(format_text):
    return "Please provide a valid {}".format(format_text)
userInput = ""

def handleUserInput(beginProgram):
global userInput
try:
    if beginProgram:
        userInput = int(input("Please select one of the options listed above. "))
    elif userInput == 1:
        userFahrenheit = float(input("Fahrenheit : "))
        print(fahren_to_celsius(userFahrenheit))
    elif userInput == 2:
        userCelsius = int(input("Celsius : "))
        print(celsius_to_fahrenheit(userCelsius))
    elif userInput == 3:
        userCelsius = int(input("Celsius"))
        print(celsius_to_kelvin(userCelsius))
    elif userInput == 4:
        userKelvin = float(input("Kelvin : "))
        print(kelvin_to_celsius(userKelvin))
    elif userInput == 5:
        userAb = float(input("Number : "))
        print(integer_to_absolute(userAb))
except ValueError:
    if beginProgram:
        print(print_error_message("integer."))
        return False
        # on false somehow throw a continue outside of this function, no idea how.
    elif userInput == 1:
        print(print_error_message("fahrenheit temprature."))
        return False
    elif userInput == 2:
        print(print_error_message("celsius temprature."))
        return False
    elif userInput == 3:
        print(print_error_message("celsius temprature."))
        return False
    elif userInput == 4:
        print(print_error_message("kelvin temprature."))
        return False
    elif userInput == 5:
        print(print_error_message("number."))
        return False

print("""1 = Fahrenheit to celsius.
2 = Celsius to fahrenheit.
3 = Celsius to kelvin.
4 = Kelvin to celsius.
5 = Absolute number calculation.""")

while True:
    handleUserInput(True)
    handleUserInput(False)
```

Comment: Your title needs to reflect what it is your code actually does.  Adding a description to your question is also likely to get you more answers.

Comment: @forsvarir Yes, exactly. In addition you should fix your indentation.

Comment: Why is there an absolute number calculator mixed in with the temperature unit converter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the if-elif block with a dictionary containing userInput as keys.

```
def show_result(choice):
    value = float(input("Value : "))
    options = {1: fahren_to_celsius(value), 2: celsius_to_fahrenheit(value), 3: celsius_to_kelvin(value),
           4: kelvin_to_celsius(value), 5: integer_to_absolute(value)}
    return options[choice]
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview! This is a positive answer as it improves the code. To make it better you may state why this is better than the given code (reduction of repetition). As a general policy we refrain from answering closed question though, so keep this in mind for the future.